# Using PonyDebugger with Monotouch?

Tags: ios, core-data, xamarin.ios, nsurlconnection, ponydebugger

[Ponydebugger](http://corner.squareup.com/2012/08/ponydebugger-remote-debugging.html) looks like a very useful tool.

Is there any way to use it with Xamarin's [Monotouch](http://xamarin.com/features)?

Comment: You can also use Fiddler2 and use your PC as a proxy server to view network traffic on an iOS device.  Here is Fiddler: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/  There is another one for Mac, I think called CharlesProxy, although I have not used it.

Comment: I use Charles on the mac. It's cheap and very good. it'll even do SSL decryption if you make your app accept any cert (one line of code)

Comment: @jonathanpeppers: Thanks for the hint, this is what I have been doing for the past 2 years. But still, it would be nice not to have to run both a Windows PC and Mac for iOS development. Charles might be a good alternative as it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a very nice approach (I won't pray for rain but there's a long weekend coming in... ;-).

At first look you should be able to use it with MonoTouch just like any other native library (i.e. create bindings) and link the `.a` with your application.

The **good** news is that it should be relatively simple since the API is small (versus the code base and the features you get).

The **bad** news is that I'm pretty sure it won't, **without changes**, handle `System.Net.WebClient`, `HttpWebRequest` ... since they are not built on top of `NSUrl*` classes.

Comment: Any news 7 years later? It would be great to have something like this to ease up debugging and troubleshooting Xamarin Forms/iOS apps? By what I searched on Nuget and Github, it doesn't seem that it exists currently. Anyone has other information?